# Why is DateTimeFormatter is not printing date in specified format?

Tags: java, parsing, jodatime

My code:

```
DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormat.forPattern("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS");
DateTime dt = formatter.parseDateTime("2014-04-24 18:22:01.867");
System.out.println("dt : "+dt);
```

Output:

```
dt : 2014-04-24T18:22:01.867+05:30
```

Expected output should be the same `String`:

```
dt : 2014-04-24 18:22:01.867
```

Answer (score 2):

The reason your output isn't the same thing is because you aren't using the formatter to do your printing. The formatter isn't "paired" with the `DateTime`, you have to explicitly use it.

Try this:

```
DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormat.forPattern("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS");
DateTime dt = formatter.parseDateTime("2014-04-24 18:22:01.867");
System.out.println("dt : " + fomatter.print(dt));
```

Comment: It means that although we are parsing the date string with the formatter, dt  object will contain the value in the 2014-04-24T18:22:01.867+05:30 format.

Comment: @ArpanPaliwal no, it will contain the value in its own internal, non human readable format, probably using the a `long millis` value. The default conversion is probably built into the `toString()` method, but the bottom line is that "displaying the data" and "storing the data" are completely separate behaviors.